# ¿Cómo crear un plugin para Android y usarlo en Unity?

Tags: android, c++, unity2d

He estado buscando durante un buen rato y no he logrado dar con la solución, lo único que pregunto es como crear (compilar) una libreria .so a partir de un cpp y un header, o mejor dicho que programa puedo o debo utilizar para dicho objetivo?

Aqui dejo un ejemplo:

### ejemlo.h:

```
#ifndef VALUE_H
#define VALUE_H

#ifdef _cplusplus 
extern "C"
{
#endif
      __declspec(dllexport) int GetValue();

#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

### ejemplo.cpp:

```
#include "value.h"

#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C" 
{
#endif

int GetValue(){
    return 10;
}

#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif

}
```

Comment: Tienes unos cuántos typos en tu pregunta. Además no estaría de más indicar qué has intentado ya (con `gcc`, por ejemplo). Ah, ¡Bienvenido!

Comment: Claro una disculpa, efectivamente como te habrás dado cuenta soy nuevo en el foro, y honestamente no tengo suficiente experiencia en como redactar las preguntas xP.
He intentado con g++ pero todos los tutorials que he visto se hacen con linux, con el cual no estoy para nada familiarizado.
También intente utilizar Android Studio con la ndk pero no me hallé para nada con el entorno.

P.D: Gracias por la bienvenida :)

Comment: Si realmente quieres programar con este tipo de archivos te recomiendo que instales linux... si queires seguir con windows mírate este link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365850/run-c-in-command-prompt-windows